# Grid incorrect Date Issue in admin custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

custom admin grid is showing incorrect date & time .in my database its showing correct also in view detail page its showing correct but in my grid its showing incorrect

Database Date is : 2015-04-10 21:10:54

Grid date is showing incorrect :  Apr 10, 2015 4:20:45 PM

I am using the below Code in my grid :

```
  $this->addColumn('created_date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Date'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'index'     => 'created_date',
            'width'     => '150px',
        ));
```

at the time of save the date i am using the below Code :
   `'created_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`,

its showing in database correct but in grid its showing incorrect

Any Help much be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the format option to your colum definition. Your column definition should look like

```
$this->addColumn('created_date', array( 
     'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Date'), 
     'align' =>    'left', 
     'type' => 'datetime', 
     'index' => 'created_date', 
     'format' => 'Y-m-d HH:MM:ss' , 
     'width' => '150px'
));
```

Then the date is displayed correctly in the grid.

Comment: After adding your changes its showing like 2015-04-10 04:20:45  , but my correct date in database is   : 2015-04-10 21:10:54

Comment: I think that your time is converted by using a timezone according to Mage_Core_Model_Locale around line 488 and Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Datetime round line 73. One solution would be to use a custom renderer for the datetime which does not make use of the $useTimezone flag.

Comment: Can you please Share snippet so will understand

Comment: You need a custom datetime renderer which overrides the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Datetime` renderer. You need to override the render method and adjust the call to the date method of the locale class. The call should look like `Mage::app()->getLocale()
                    ->date($data, Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT, null, false)->toString($format);`. The important part is the last parameter to which omits the conversion to the timezone from the locale.

Comment: @luemic ur above comment should be the accepted answer :)